# Django UpdateView / ImageField issue: not returning new uploaded image

Tags: python, django, imagefield

model:

```
class Logo(models.Model):
    media = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.media.url
```

view:

```
class LogoEdit(UpdateView):
  model = Logo
  template_name = 'polls/logo-edit.html'
  success_url = '/polls/logos/'

  def form_valid(self, form):
    pdb.set_trace()
```

template:

```
  <form id="my_form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
  </form>
```

selecting new image:

[form](http://ctrlv.in/513134)

debug view:

existing image:

```
(Pdb) self.object
<Logo: media/uploads/DSCN0844.JPG>
```

form with new selected image (DSC_0021.JPG):

```
(Pdb) test = form.save()
(Pdb) test
<Logo: media/uploads/DSCN0844.JPG>
```

As you can see the original image remains in form!

Comment: Can you please explicitly ask a question? E.g. I don't see anywhere in your template that you are trying to render the uploaded image.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using `UpdateView`, you only need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the form tag in your template. The rest will be handled by `UpdateView` class.

Comment: <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> - it worked, thank you

Comment: Had the same issue, adding <enctype="multipart/form-data"> to the form solved it!

Answer (score 6):

You need to save the form providing request.FILES:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

And in your HTML form (since you have an `<input type="file">` in the form):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> - That was it, thank you

Answer (score 3):

just add to your template

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```